# can't click on input element behind div element

Tags: html, css

On my site: http://alsite.com.br/solalev/ I have some elements on the bottom of page that I can't click through.  Above the elements is a div called push.. I use this div to make the footer always stay on the bottom of my page even when the content is smaller... (I dont know if I do this right.. but it has worked)..

So.. on Chrome and Firefox I can't click.. but on IE this works....

I use this:

```
.push{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

but nothing happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using `pointer-events: none;` so much in your CSS? If not then just get rid of it as this is what's causing the problems.

Having looked a bit closer your problem is the .wrapper div. You have a height of 231px on your .push div and a margin-bottom of -231px on your .wrapper to create a sticky footer. I would find a better way of creating sticky footers as this one is far from ideal. Perhaps the one suggested in these answers might help or use this tried and tested approach

[CSS Tricks Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

or

[JQuery Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: the `CSS Tricks Sticky Footer` is awesome!.. very nice.. thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `pointer-events: none;` from your css properties (html, body, wrapper, baixo, push, footer). It seems you wanted to disable all mouse events and now wonder why nothing's happening on mouse click?

Answer (score 0):

seems like the .push is a bad way to make your footer stay at the bottom... Here is another way to do it:

**HTML**

```
<html>
     <head>
          <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div id="paddingFix">
               <div id="content">
                   <!-- Your content goes here. -->
               </div>

               <div id="footer">Footer</div>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#paddingFix {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:60px;
    text-align:center;
}

#footer {
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    background:black;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nubx/b38Z5/3/)

Basicly it positions the footer at the absolute bottom of a container that is min-height:100%; and position relative; the all the content is in the container aswell with a padding-bottom at the size of the footer's height plus a little of space.

Comment: You might want to set the foreground color in the footer; as the 'as' disappears since it's black on black.

Comment: Man... this works on high resolutions... but if i open the site on smaller resolution (1024x768) the footer is hovering the content...

u can see example on: http://alsite.com.br/solalev/teste.asp

Comment: http://alsite.com.br/solalev/css/layout2.css padding-bottom:60px;  needs to be the height of the footer, + the space you want from the footer to your content...

Comment: Try padding-bottom:290px; on  #content instead of 60

Comment: the link that trickeedickee provide works well.. and i need to modify small elements on my pages.. thanks for help!

Comment: Cool, it is also a good solution, i just prefer this, it's more simple :) But i assure you, changing it from 60 to 290 would have fixed the problem aswell...

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the negative margin on you wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Then get rid of your div.push all together (remove it from the HTML code). And lastly, remove the "pointer-events".

Now your footer will always be just below the content, and the users will be albe to fill in the form.

Also, more out of curiosity, but it looks like most of the code is done with DIVs (proper) until the footer. Then, boom, it is table city (not to mention a style sheet and meta tag randomly stuck in there)! Is the footer coming from a third party?