# Simple background color div without white space

Tags: whitespace, css

Trying to create a content box that has a background color of white. It is inbetween the header div and footer div which are both images. I can't get it to align with the two divs AND have it without white space, only one or the other.

This is the CSS:

```
#content {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:1024px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How do I get the content box to align with the rest of the page and not have any whitespaces?

This is what it looks like at the moment, I want to get rid of the space between the HELLO box and the images above and below it.

[image: This is what it looks like at the moment, I want to get rid of the space between the HELLO box and the images above and below it.]

Comment: Maybe it will be more easy to understand if you could post your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/? I'm lost :)

Comment: We need more of your code. At least the css for the images, and the html would be nice also.

Comment: Hmmm, so you want a header at the top, and a footer at the bottom, and the content in between? And the content needs to be from the bottom of the header and the top of the footer? Or something like that?

Comment: I'm not to familiar with jsfiddle, but this is what the code is like:http://jsfiddle.net/xaEc8/

Comment: Yes, right now it goes: HEADER (image) [WHITESPACE] CONTENT (background color) [WHITESPACE] FOOTER (image).... does that make sense?

Comment: not really, try to illustrate what you want a little more. Just made a awencer here, maybe it can help you aswell? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318688/973485

Comment: Look at the image i added to my post at the top

Comment: Your JS Fiddle doesn't resemble your illustration in any way (except for the word 'hello'); help us to help you, demonstrate your *actual* problem, and clearly explain that problem; then we can help.

Comment: I think the image I posted at my original question at the top of this page will illustrate my problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a great solution, but with the given information it's the only one i can come up with.

**CSS**

```
#content {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:1024px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;

    position:relative;
}

#topWhiteFix, #botWhiteFix {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    height:12px;
    width:100%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

#topWhiteFix {
    top:-12px;
}

#botWhiteFix {
    bottom:-12px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
     <div id="topWhiteFix"></div>
     <div id="botWhiteFix"></div>

     HELLO
</div>
```

(Untested)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem as a clean solution to me, but here I go:

```
#content { 
margin-top: -15px; margin-bottom: -15px; 
}
```

Actually I don't know if -15px is good enough, you should try your own values.